# how to put child element ontop of parent

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following issue.

This is my html code:

```
<div className="search_artist ">
    <p className="search_artist__heading">Find a band/artist</p>
    <div className="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr"/><button className="btn"onClick={this.searchArtists}>Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my SCSS:

```
.search_artist {
    margin: 44px auto;
    width: 908px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    opacity: 0.15;
    position: relative;
}

.search_artist > * {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.search_artist__heading {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: white;
}
```

Im trying to put all children elements under `search_artist` to be on top of the div so that the opacity doesn't affect them.

Can I please get any input as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opacity property is inherited by all child element of a parent. I suppose you need opacity for a background and you tried using opacity property. You can try using a background color with alpha (opacity). Example:

```
parent{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.3)
}
```

First 3 values are normal rgb values, last one is alpha (opacity) with values 0 to 1

Answer (score 3):

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

> Note: When using the opacity property to add transparency to the background of an element, all of its child elements become transparent as well. This can make the text inside a fully transparent element hard to read. If you do not want to apply opacity to child elements, use RGBA color values instead (See "More Examples" below).

`opacity` applies to all the child elements. It doesn't matter if elements are "on top of the div" as you state (and I believe you're trying to achieve this through z-index but these are all still children of the parent, so the z-index doesn't matter). If you just want the background color to be opaque, then you can see a RGB background color instead with transparency, rather than the `opacity` attribute. Does this answer your question?

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Ill have to read through it more thoroughly!